# React Native Firebase Dynamic Links Please

Tags: reactjs, firebase, react-native, firebase-dynamic-links

I am using Firebase Dynamic link I am successfully creating a link but when i am testing it the link is opening but I cannot get the dynamic link.

```
const HandleDeepLink = () => {
const navigation = useNavigation();

const handleDynamicLink = link => {
Handle dynamic link inside your own application
console.log('link', link)
>     };

useEffect(() => {
const unsubscribe = dynamicLinks().onLink(handleDynamicLink);
When the component is unmounted, remove the listener
return () => unsubscribe();
[]);

return null;
>   }

useEffect(() => {
dynamicLinks()
>       .getInitialLink()
>       .then(link => {
console.log('link', link)
>       });
[]);
```

here is the code.

I tried different listener but nothings work.

Answer (score 0):

I've got the same issue when testing with emulator/simulator, I have to work around with Linking:

```
import DeviceInfo from 'react-native-device-info';
...

useEffect(() => {
    let linkingSubscription: EmitterSubscription;
    if (__DEV__ && DeviceInfo.isEmulatorSync()) {
       linkingSubscription = Linking.addEventListener('url', ({ url }) => {
           console.log('Linking eventListener', url);
          // do something
       });
    }
    return () => {
       linkingSubscription?.remove();
    };
}, []);
```

Please be aware that the Dynamic Links will be shut down in 2025-08-25.